# jpackage - missing .jpackage.xml file

Tags: java, deb, jpackage

I am an amateur so may not have the terminology correct!  I have followed instructions from a textbook to produce a modular, stripped down jre from a database application which uses a postgresql remote datbase and jdbc postgresql driver.  I followed the steps using jar, jmod, jdeps and jlink, and now have a release folder which contains a bin folder which contains a 'script shell' from which I can launch the application.
My textbook details the final step (to produce .deb package) as (from the folder directly above the release folder):

```
jpackage --name MyInstaller --app-image ./release/
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: Missing .jpackage.xml file in app-image dir "./release"
```

I have googled but have come up with nothing that solves it, although I did find a self-answered post on this site wherein the user did track down such an .xml file (but I can't find such a file anywhere).

I am running an Ubuntu 20.04 Virtualbox VM and openjdk 20.0.2 (according to java -version).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially the problem is that there's not nearly enough info to complete the task. Here's an (already pretty minimal) example that works for me:

```
jpackage \
--dest /tmp/xcode/jpackage \
--type app-image \
--app-version '1.0' \
--copyright 'Copyright' \
--description 'Description' \
--name 'appname' \
--vendor 'Vendor' \
--runtime-image /tmp/xcode/jlink/runtime-image \
--module-path target/classes \
--module com.technojeeves.xcode/com.technojeeves.xcode.XCode \
--arguments '--opt' \
--java-options '-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Xms256m -Xmx512m' \
--type deb
```

Probably best saved as a shell script that you can tweak

Comment: I think my lack of knowledge is coming into play here.  The app-image I assumed was the file in the release folder which launches my application, how is that different from the runtime-image?  I tried your suggestions, and got various errors, which probably come down to my lack of knowledge.  The first error I got was:Bundler DEB Bundle skipped because of a configuration problem: java.lang.module.FindException: Two versions of module my.module found in . (my.module.jmod and my.jar).  I then tweaked like mad but got various errors.  I was frustrated because the command in the book didn't work.

Comment: The app-image afaik refers to the whole folder which is essentially produced by the `jlink` procedure. Which "book" are we talking about - is it viewable online?

Comment: I'm afraid it isn't, it's a French language book.  His final command, executed in a build folder one level up from the release folder (created by jlink) is:  jpackage --name moninstaller --app-image ./release/ (which is as you say the folder produced by jlink.

Comment: These are the commands that took me thus far: jar cf build/my.jar * , jmod create --class-path build/my.jar --main-class pac.com.Starter build/my.module.jmod , jdeps --list-deps --ignore-missing-deps build/my.jar pac/com/postgresql-42.5.4.jar , and finally jlink --output build/release --add-modules java.base,java.desktop,java.logging,java.management,java.naming,java.security.jgss,java.security.sasl,java.sql,java.transaction.xa,java.xml,my.module --module-path build/my.module.jmod --launcher MyApp=my.module/pac.com.Starter  He does wind up by saying jpackage can do everything jlink does.

Comment: What attracts you to this particularly - is it that you happen to want that particular application?

Comment: I didn't touch Java for quite a long time, and felt quite intimidated by the modularity that had been introduced.  I tried writing a database app, just for the experience , got the book to brush up and learn modules. Then was surprised at getting as far as an app that could run on another machine without full jre. Was frustrated that the final step of deb packaging didn't work.  Actually today I realised all I needed to do was right click the release folder and I can immediately have zip folder which I successfully ran on another VM.  Hope you don't feel I wasted your time

Comment: Didn't have enough characters to say thanks, I appreciate the help!  It would be nice if I could get it to work, it's obvious I don't understand as much as I thought I did!  But creating a zip or tar seems a workaround.

Comment: If you put up a link to the tar.gz (just the source) I can take a look. The objective presumably is to get the .deb file so you can use it to install?

Comment: I actually chose a zip file, which, as I say, worked fine.  It's very good of you to offer, but really my code is embarrassingly amateurish, I have a lot of tidying up to do.  The need for an installer is very much in the future and hypothetical!